# SQL Server stored procedure: wait for a delete's trigger to finish before continuing in the procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers, audit

My stored procedure executes a delete statement that sets off a trigger that can't record who deleted the row, but records a blank for `changed_by`.

Then the stored procedure updates the `changed_by` with the username it was given.

Half the time, part 2 of the below stored procedure finds the results of the trigger, the other half of the time, it doesn't find the results of the trigger, so there is nothing to update.

How can I "yield" control and ensure the update's trigger finishes before continuing with the stored procedure?

(In comments you see some things I've tried so far that haven't worked)

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dbo.deleteAndUpdateChangedByInAuditTrail
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.deleteAndUpdateChangedByInAuditTrail 
     (@tableName VARCHAR(100), 
      @pkIDColName VARCHAR(100), 
      @pkIDValue NUMERIC,
      @delUser VARCHAR(100) )
AS
     BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        -- PART 1: DO THE DELETE:
        DECLARE @JUST_BEFORE_DELETION_TIMESTAMP AS DATETIME2;

        SET @JUST_BEFORE_DELETION_TIMESTAMP = CONVERT(varchar, SYSDATETIME(), 121);

        DECLARE @DELETION_TEMPLATE AS VARCHAR(MAX);
        SET @DELETION_TEMPLATE = 'delete from {THE_TABLE_NAME} WHERE {PK_ID_COL_NAME} = {PK_ID_VALUE}';
        SET @DELETION_TEMPLATE = REPLACE(@DELETION_TEMPLATE, '{THE_TABLE_NAME}', @tableName);
        SET @DELETION_TEMPLATE = REPLACE(@DELETION_TEMPLATE, '{PK_ID_COL_NAME}', @pkIDColName);
        SET @DELETION_TEMPLATE = REPLACE(@DELETION_TEMPLATE, '{PK_ID_VALUE}', @pkIDValue);

        --PRINT @DELETION_TEMPLATE
        EXEC (@DELETION_TEMPLATE);

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        -- PART 2: UPDATE THE AUDIT_TRAIL:

        DECLARE @TOTAL_NUM_ROWS_UPDATED_WITH_USERNAME AS NUMERIC;
        SET @TOTAL_NUM_ROWS_UPDATED_WITH_USERNAME = 0;

        --DECLARE @TOTAL_TRIES_SO_FAR AS NUMERIC;
        --SET @TOTAL_TRIES_SO_FAR = 0;

        --WHILE @TOTAL_NUM_ROWS_UPDATED_WITH_USERNAME < 1 AND @TOTAL_TRIES_SO_FAR < 5
        --BEGIN  

            --SET @TOTAL_TRIES_SO_FAR = @TOTAL_TRIES_SO_FAR + 1;

            --WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01.000' -- SEEN IT FAIL FOR 4 SECONDS :(

            DECLARE @UPDATE_AUDIT_TRAIL_TEMPLATE AS VARCHAR(MAX);

            SET @UPDATE_AUDIT_TRAIL_TEMPLATE = 'update AUDIT_TRAIL set changed_by = ''{CHANGED_BY}'' WHERE upper(table_name) = upper(''{THE_TABLE_NAME}'') and table_pk_value = {PK_ID_VALUE} and CONVERT(varchar, changed_at, 121) >= ''{CHANGED_AT}'' ';

            SET @UPDATE_AUDIT_TRAIL_TEMPLATE = REPLACE(@UPDATE_AUDIT_TRAIL_TEMPLATE, '{CHANGED_BY}', @delUser); 
            SET @UPDATE_AUDIT_TRAIL_TEMPLATE = REPLACE(@UPDATE_AUDIT_TRAIL_TEMPLATE, '{THE_TABLE_NAME}', @tableName); 
            SET @UPDATE_AUDIT_TRAIL_TEMPLATE = REPLACE(@UPDATE_AUDIT_TRAIL_TEMPLATE, '{PK_ID_VALUE}', @pkIDValue); 
            SET @UPDATE_AUDIT_TRAIL_TEMPLATE = REPLACE(@UPDATE_AUDIT_TRAIL_TEMPLATE, '{CHANGED_AT}', @JUST_BEFORE_DELETION_TIMESTAMP); 

            --PRINT @UPDATE_AUDIT_TRAIL_TEMPLATE

            EXEC (@UPDATE_AUDIT_TRAIL_TEMPLATE);

            SELECT @TOTAL_NUM_ROWS_UPDATED_WITH_USERNAME = @@ROWCOUNT;

        --END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    RETURN @TOTAL_NUM_ROWS_UPDATED_WITH_USERNAME;
GO
```

Comment: You shouldn't (as in absolutely **Never**) compare dates as strings. Use appropriate datatypes, it's what they are there for, and I have little doubt it's the cause for your current issue. You should also **always** define the length of a `varchar`.

Comment: thank you , I changed to SYSDATETIME(), still was getting the error, then switched to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, and all seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Triggers don't get executed asynchronously.   The next step after the DELETE will not happen until the trigger is finished.

If you are seeing something that makes you think otherwise, there is some other reason for it.   It's not because the trigger "didn't finish".